# No image displayed with highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using this code to generate the graph, But when I run the same, I get no image on my brwoser. I tested the code on IE, chrome and firefox.

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js">
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Jan',
                    'Feb',
                    'Mar',
                    'Apr',
                    'May',
                    'Jun',
                    'Jul',
                    'Aug',
                    'Sep',
                    'Oct',
                    'Nov',
                    'Dec'
                ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

            }]
        });
    </script>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<input type = "button" name="submit" value="Generate">
<button id="highcharts">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with the code?
Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to close `});` and also close `<script>` properly (`../exporting.js"> </script>`), check full source

You also need to add jquery plugin.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"> </script>
<script>
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Jan',
                    'Feb',
                    'Mar',
                    'Apr',
                    'May',
                    'Jun',
                    'Jul',
                    'Aug',
                    'Sep',
                    'Oct',
                    'Nov',
                    'Dec'
                ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

            }]
        });
       });
    </script>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tp4LS/1/)

Comment: hey can I just remove this button thing and get the chart displayed whenever i go to the url of the script in which this code is embedded ?

Comment: yes, u can remove buttons, I just copied pasted thought You are gonna use it somewhere. I've updated answer by removing necessary things.

Comment: Hey I have one more thing to ask.. for xAxis I am passing js_array. The problem here is for the first bar it is not taking anyvalue from the array. beofre converting it to js_array, my array was like - 
**[array](http://pastebin.com/sXSMmYaG)**

Answer (score 0):

There was incomplete js code at the end. function started ("$(function () {") must be completed with "});". You also need to add jquery plugin.

```
$(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: [
                        'Jan',
                        'Feb',
                        'Mar',
                        'Apr',
                        'May',
                        'Jun',
                        'Jul',
                        'Aug',
                        'Sep',
                        'Oct',
                        'Nov',
                        'Dec'
                    ]
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                    footerFormat: '</table>',
                    shared: true,
                    useHTML: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Tokyo',
                    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

                }, {
                    name: 'New York',
                    data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

                }, {
                    name: 'London',
                    data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

                }, {
                    name: 'Berlin',
                    data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

                }]
            });
          });
```

try this out http://jsfiddle.net/zZ9e2/

Answer (score 0):

I've got a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UGL4K/). To get it working:

- Include Jquery: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`
- Add a missing: `});`